# Nginx to IIS reverse proxy at different path

Tags: nginx, iis, proxy

I have a website that is hosted at http://server/subdir1/subdir2/ that is hosted on an IIS server at http://dotnet/subdir1/subdir2/website where the subdir1/subdir2 portion of each is the same.

I have the following.

```
location /subdir1/subdir2 {
   rewrite ^/subdir1/subdir2/website(/.*)$ $1 break;
   proxy_pass http://dotnet/subdir1/subdir2/website;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

When I browse to http://server/subdir1/subdir2 or http://server/subdir1/subdir2/validpath it works fine but clicking on any links send me to http://server/subdir1/subdir2/website/validpath which doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: When responses coming from IIS, you should ask nginx to rewrite the links again.

Comment: Is sub filter the only way to do this?